# How to sort go code functions alphabetically? GoLand Code -> Rearrange Code is greyed out

Tags: go, goland

I really don't want to rearrange all of my code manually as I have unwittingly been doing for a couple months now before finally realizing my editor or some other external tool should be able to do this for me.

However the `Code -> Rearrange` menu setting option is greyed out.

`Settings -> Editor -> Go` has no mention of rearranging or matching functions.

Has this functionality not been ported over to GoLand yet?

Answer (score 3):

You're right, this functionality is not available in GoLand yet, please see and follow [GO-2270](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-2270).

Comment: thanks I will track the issue